# Combining, sum and renaming rows in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following Data

```
--------------------------------------------------
| code |      name    | qty | 
--------------------------------------------------
| FZH      | apple | 3 |
--------------------------------------------------
| ZH2      | orange| 7 |
--------------------------------------------------
| H26     | mt dew | 5 |
--------------------------------------------------
| 6YS      | pear | 7 |
--------------------------------------------------
| LKZ      | coke | 4 |
--------------------------------------------------
```

Using pandas I want to tell it to sum the apple, orange, and pear and write

```
| 2DC     | FRUIT | 17 |
```

The actual list of fruit is a lot longer. "Bananas" is sometimes on the list for the day and I want it to sum that too but skip it if it does not find it. 
I want to do a similar thing with all of the sodas, using my list of possible sodas needed for the day

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you're trying to filter, then sum. You can use `loc`, `isin`, and `sum`:

```
fruits = ["apple", "orange", "pear"]

df.loc[df["name"].isin(fruits)].qty.sum()
```

Comment: Cleaner way would be: `df.loc[df["name"].isin(fruits), 'qty'].sum()`